# VBA "On Error Goto" not surpassing the Errors

Tags: excel, vba

Solution By Damian works but Does anyone know Why `On Error Goto` doesn't surpass every type of error in the screenshot, it passes `#DIV/0!` but not any other error.

I am writing a code to **Clean Trim** all the cells in the workbook. With luck I am able to do it with the below code.

```
 On Error GoTo c

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

        Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

        For Each cl In rng

                Debug.Print cl.Address
                cl.Value = WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(cl.Value))
                GoTo l
c:

counter = counter + 1

l:
        Next

    Next
```

But the Problem arises when any of the cells contain Error Values like in the Screenshot below.

[image: Errors]

VBA's `On Error Goto` is able to surpass the `#DIV/0!` error and allocate the value to the counter but not for the other errors. It gets stuck on those cells.

Comment: `On Error` triggers for me on `#N/A`, so not entirely sure what the deal is here. I assume the cells contain the actual error, and not the error number or descriptor or just the text "#N/A" for example? "#N/A" is a string, not an error, so if this is the case - that is why the code doesn't catch it. Check this by entering `=NA()` as a formula in some cell, it simulates the `#N/A` error. Your code should trigger on this.

Comment: @Vegard  ... Here is the file with code  ... (https://drive.google.com/open?id=17H07sqzVIFOMj2psHTq6cduPq2kiUSqc) .. If you see, Error Handler should skip all the Errors, but it is only skipping `#DIV/0!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problems:

```
 On Error GoTo c
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        Set Rng = ws.UsedRange 'activesheet will always be the sheet you are using clicking the macro button
        For Each cl In Rng
                Debug.Print cl.Address
                If Not IsError(cl) Then cl = WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(cl)) 'check first if the value is an error, if it's not then trim
                GoTo l
c:
counter = counter + 1
l:
        Next

    Next
```

Thought using `UsedRange` will loop through all the cells even if they are blank but once were used. Beware of that.

Comment: He want to count the errors. Your solution doesn't help with that.

Comment: @Damian ..... This solved my problem at hand, but do you know why `On Error Resume Next ` isn't surpassing these errors ?

Comment: @Adirmola nowhere in his code he was counting the errors.

Comment: @MohitBansal I can't tell you that because I'm not so sure, but I can tell you that it works after something happens but in this case since the cell is an error it can't evaluate the cell hence the error. Using `IsError(Cell)` will allow you to handle cells with errors.

Comment: @Damian ... I am counting the errors in the Variable `counter`, but it's fine. I have amended your solution in my code and it's working fine. I am though still wondering about the On Error Resume Next.

Comment: Right, I'm still sleepy, you could get rid of the `On Error GoTo c` and the `c:` label with my code, just checking if was an error then adding the counter.